# lilo.conf questions

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, lilo

I use lilo, and have two different kernels. One is newer and use KMS with it.

What I would like to do, is to be able to set vga=xxx for only one of the kernels.

Is this possible?

I would also like to be able to code into lilo.conf options that I pass on the commandline, but am unsure how to do this

edit:

adding my current lilo.conf

```
append=" vt.default_utf8=0"
boot = /dev/sda
prompt
timeout = 1200
change-rules
  reset
other = /dev/sda1
  label = Windows
  table = /dev/sda
image = /boot/bzImage-2.6.33.2
  root = /dev/sda5
  label = Test
  read-only
image = /boot/bzImage-2.6.31
  root = /dev/sda5
  label = Older
  vga = 791
  read-only
```

Comment: wow, blast from the past.  my answer below jives with what i recall from the last decade, but i haven't used LILO in quite some time so i may be forgetting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an [old LILO manpage](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/5lilo.conf.man.html) you'd use the *vga* option for one kernel section in your *lilo.conf* but not the other.  Example:

```
[...]
image = /zImage-1.0.9
        label = 1.0.9

image = /tamu/vmlinuz
        label = tamu
        root = /dev/hdb2
        vga = ask
[...]
```

The *vga* parameter can be given any standard response (that is, any value the kernel will understand; I believe LILO will simply pass any value set to the kernel):

> **vga** = *mode*
>   This specifies the VGA text mode that should be selected when booting. The following values are recognized (case is ignored):
>
> - **normal**: select normal 80x25 text mode.
> - **extended** (or **ext**): select 80x50 text mode.
> - **ask**: stop and ask for user input (at boot time).
> - **[number]**: use the corresponding text mode. A list of available modes can be obtained by booting with vga=ask and pressing [Enter].
>
> If this variable is omitted, the VGA mode setting contained in the kernel image is used. (And that is set at compile time using the SVGA_MODE variable in the kernel Makefile, and can later be changed with the rdev(8) program.)

For additional kernel options that LILO doesn't understand, [use the *append* keyword](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel-lilo.html) in *lilo.conf*:

```
[...]
image = /tamu/vmlinuz
        label = tamu
        root = /dev/hdb2
        vga = ask
        append="iwlagn.swcrypto=1"
[...]
```

**Don't forget to rerun LILO after changing *lilo.conf* to pick up the changes.**

Comment: At the moment I have the cga option set for one kernel as per your example, but it currently occurs for every kernel I boot with.

Likewise I wanted to add the option iwlagn.swcrypto=1 for a particular kernel, but running lilo just results in an error. Rather than have the option on a operate line, should I have it after the path of the kernel?

Comment: @jack: hopefully you mean the *vga* option... i can't remember, but i think LILO only recognizes a few kernel options in this format.  use the *append* option for others.  adding another example now...

Comment: Hi quack, thanks, I will try out the append option later, it should solve my problem. However the vga paramter does not work as it should. I have pasted my lilo.conf above, and when I boot test, which is the kernel with KMS enabled, I have to manually tell it to continue whenit complaines about the vga line. Removing it solves the problem...